# Excel macro is closing automatically

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run the macro code, it is closing automatically without executing the code. This issue is only in my remote machine not in the local.
Is this issue relates with Excel version or my remote machine. Can anyone help me on this issue.

For example sample code:

```
Sub test
    MsgBox "a"
End Sub
```

Comment: Which module do you have this in?

Comment: Macro security settings different on the remote machine?